# Order of network ports (portid's) in a dpdk application

Tags: dpdk

In my dpdk application, I want to use three network interfaces, two PCI and one tap interface. The below are the parameters that I'm passing to my dpdk application:

--vdev=net_tap0,mac=fixed -a '00:08.0' -a '00:09.0'

Is there a way to know which portid's they map to without starting the dpdk application. More specifically, what is the order in which dpdk assigns portid's to the interfaces?

EDIT: I ran the `dpdk-proc-info` program as suggested and got the below error report:

```
EAL: RTE Version: 'DPDK 20.11.1'
EAL: failed to send to (/var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket) due to Connection refused
EAL: Fail to send request /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket:bus_vdev_mp vdev_scan(): Failed to request vdev from primary
EAL: failed to send to (/var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket) due to Connection refused
EAL: Fail to send request /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket:eal_vfio_mp_sync
EAL:   cannot request default container fd
EAL: VFIO support could not be initialized
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL: Requested device 0000:00:08.0 cannot be used
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL: Requested device 0000:00:09.0 cannot be used
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1   Cause: No primary DPDK process is running.
```

From the above error report, it appears that a dpdk app needs to be running first to use `dpdk-proc-info`

Comment: thanks for the proc-info update, it give insight to DPDK version you are using. Yes this is expected because proc-info is a secondary process. But using proc-info one can see the order of the port numbering with various combination of vdev and pcie allow. Answer to your dpdk version is updates, please read and accept to close the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DPDK 18.11 LTS onwards the order of device probe is set as ***first virtual second physical device on PCIe device.***

With DPDK 20.11 LTS onwards the order of device probe is set as ***first physical PCIe device & second virtual device.***

[EDIT-1 based on comment conversation Fractal is using DPDk > = 20.11]Hence with the option `--vdev=net_tap0,mac=fixed -a '00:08.0' -a '00:09.0'` the result is

1. DPDK port 0 - 00:08.0
2. DPDK port 1 - 00:09.0
3. DPDK port 2 - vdev=net_tap0

For any DPDK application giving hints on actual port order, one can use `dpdk-proc-info` by running with options **sudo ./dpdk-proc-info  -a 0000:83:00.1 -a 0000:81:00.0  -v**

One can also modify DPDK example `hellworld` to identify the order as

```
uint16_t portid = 0;
RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid) {
    struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
    if (rte_eth_dev_info_get(portid, &dev_info) == 0)
    {
        printf("port %u... %s\n", portid, dev_info.driver_name);
    }
}
```

CMD to run: ***helloworld-binary -l 1 `--vdev=net_tap0,mac=fixed -a '00:08.0' -a '00:09.0***

result:

```
port 0... net_i40e
port 1... net_i40e
port 2... net_tap
hello from core 1
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. The `dpdk-proc-info` is expecting some config file. Can you please tell me where to find the relevant config file? It appears that the program is looking for `/var/run/dpdk/rte/config` file, but it was not there on my machine(Ubuntu 20.04, DPDK 20.11)

Comment: @Fractal dpdk-proc-info does not require any config file,m ensure to run it with `sudo`

Comment: `EAL: RTE Version: 'DPDK 20.11.0'
EAL: Cannot open '/var/run/dpdk/rte/config' for rte_mem_config
EAL: FATAL: Cannot init config
EAL: Cannot init config
PANIC in main():`
I'm getting this error. with `dpdk-proc-info` program

Comment: I observeed that when my dpdk application assigned port numbers to physical interfaces first and then  to tap interfaces. So  ` DPDK port 0 - 00:08.0 ;    DPDK port 1 - 00:09.0 ;    DPDK port 2 - vdev=net_tap0`

This is what I got in my test run

Comment: @Fractal happy to hear now TAP port is recognised and you are able to get the vdev and phy order. So please accept and close the ticket. with respect to order issue share the DPDK version by running `dpdk-proc-info` with option '-v'

Comment: I'm not really sure if the order is vdev's first and pci-device's next, because I see that in my dpdk application, physical devices (1,2) got portid's first and after that only did the vdev got the portid (2). I'll update the question with the `dpdk-proc-info` error

Comment: @Fractal  I have updated the asnwer for the DPDK version 20.11 . Please read and accept to close the question.